# How to ensure Flutter processes won't be killed when app is in background mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background-process

There is a device to collect data overnight. It is sending data to a Flutter app, which uploads it to a server. What can I do to ensure that transfer processes will stay alive and won’t be killed when app will stay in background mode for a long time?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't about the Flutter! But rather the iOS system. So you need to understand how iOS or when iOS will suspend/give more time to a running app.

> Most apps can move to the suspended state easily enough but there are
>   also legitimate reasons for apps to continue running in the
>   background... When you find it necessary to keep your app running in
>   the background, iOS helps you do so efficiently and without draining
>   system resources or the user’s battery. The techniques offered by iOS
>   fall into three categories:
>
> - Apps that start a short task in the foreground can ask for time to
>     finish that task when the app moves to the background.
> - Apps that
>     initiate downloads in the foreground can hand off management of those
>     downloads to the system, thereby allowing the app to be suspended or
>     terminated while the download continues.
> - Apps that need to run in the
>     background to support specific types of tasks can declare their
>     support for one or more background execution modes.

Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html